# comparar 2 intervalos de fechas

Tags: php, laravel

Hola llevo un par de dias con un problema que ni con al ayuda de chatgpt lo consigo.

Quiero comparar un intervalo de 2 fechas (*una fecha de inicio y una fecha fin*) con varios intervalos que rescato de base de datos, es decir, quiero comparar el intervalo *2023-06-01 y 2023-06-12* con el intervalo *2023-06-04 y 2023-06-15* o el intervalo *2023-05-27 y 2023-06-03* y que me diga si algún día se cruza. En estos casos es evidente que si se cruzan estos intervalos ya que coinciden varios días entre ellos pero no se como hacerlo.

Aquí dejo la función de mi controlador para que le podais echar un vistazo, muchas gracias.

```
public function setVacaciones(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'inicio' => 'required',
        'fin' => 'required',
        'dni' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 400);
    }

    $dni = $request->input('dni');
    $vacaciones = $this->workers->getHolidays($dni);
    $interruptor = false;
    $coinciden = false;
    $fechasCoincidentes = [];
    $fechaInicio1 = $request->input('inicio');
    $fechaFin1 = $request->input('fin');
    $intervalo1 = new DateTime($fechaInicio1);
    $fechaFin1 = new DateTime($fechaFin1);

    foreach ($vacaciones as $key => $v) {


        $fechaInicio2 = $v->fecha_inicio;
        $fechaFin2 = $v->fecha_fin;


        $intervalo2 = new DateTime($fechaInicio2);
        $fechaFin2 = new DateTime($fechaFin2);



        while ($intervalo1 <= $fechaFin1) {
            if ($intervalo1 >= $intervalo2 && $intervalo1 <= $fechaFin2) {
                $coinciden = true;
                $fechasCoincidentes[] = $intervalo1->format('Y-m-d');
            }

            $intervalo1->modify('+1 day');
        }
    }

    if ($coinciden) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        $resultado = $this->workers->setHolidays($request->input('inicio'), $request->input('fin'), $request->input('dni'));

        if ($resultado) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Registro insertado correctamente'], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error al insertar el registro'], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: esta bueno el cuestionamiento dejame ver si te puedo hechar un ojo o incluso una mano...

Comment: El array `$fechasCoincidentes[]`  para qué es? y la petitición providne de un trabajador solicitando vacaciones, o de un supervisor cubriendo los turnos cuando sabe que algunos trabajadores se irán de vacaciones?

Comment: @ffflabs el array ese es para almacenar las fechas que coinciden entre los intervalos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponagmos que tenemos 2 inteverlados de fechas, `A-B` y `C-D`.
Para saber si se solapan tenemos que ver:

- Si `C >= A` y `C <= B` (*`C` entre*)

  ```
   A-----B    
      C------D
  ```
- Si `D >= A` y `D <= B` (*`D` entre*)

  ```
     A-----B
  C------D
  ```
- SI `C <= A` y `D >= B` (*`CD` contiene `AB`*)

  ```
     A-----B   
  C-----------D
  ```

Entonces, ahora solo resta hacer la comparación, por ejemplo, así:

```php
// ... código anterior

$fechaInicio1 = $request->input('inicio');
$fechaFin1 = $request->input('fin');
$coinciden = false;

$A = new DateTime($fechaInicio1);
$B = new DateTime($fechaFin1);

foreach ($vacaciones as $key => $v) {
   $fechaInicio2 = $v->fecha_inicio;
   $fechaFin2 = $v->fecha_fin;

   $C = new DateTime($fechaInicio2);
   $D = new DateTime($fechaFin2);

   // Se solapan?
   $C_entre = $C >= $A && $C <= $B;
   $D_entre = $D >= $A && $D <= $B;
   $CD_contiene = $C <= $A && $D >= $B;

   if ($C_entre || $D_entre || $CD_contiene) {
      $coinciden = true;
      break;
   }
}

// ... resto del código
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://onlinephp.io/c/0ed1d4)

Comment: Ha funcionado perfectamente mil gracias, ya estaba dandole demasiadas vueltas y no daba con la clave

Answer (score -1):

La idea que planteas es correcta... tiene sentido. Sin embargo, hay un problema en la lógica que impide que se detecten las coincidencias correctamente.

El problema radica en el uso de un bucle `while` para iterar sobre las fechas del primer intervalo y luego compararlas con el segundo intervalo. Esta implementación solo compara una fecha a la vez, lo que no es suficiente para detectar la intersección de intervalos.

En lugar de usar un bucle `while`, puedes aprovechar las funciones `max()` y `min()` para encontrar la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin de la intersección de los dos intervalos. Si las fechas de inicio y fin de la intersección coinciden, eso significa que los intervalos se cruzan.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de tu version modificada de la función `setVacaciones()` que utiliza esta lógica:

```
public function setVacaciones(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'inicio' => 'required',
        'fin' => 'required',
        'dni' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()], 400);
    }

    $dni = $request->input('dni');
    $vacaciones = $this->workers->getHolidays($dni);
    $coinciden = false;
    $fechasCoincidentes = [];
    $fechaInicio1 = $request->input('inicio');
    $fechaFin1 = $request->input('fin');
    $intervalo1 = new DateTime($fechaInicio1);
    $fechaFin1 = new DateTime($fechaFin1);

    foreach ($vacaciones as $key => $v) {
        $fechaInicio2 = $v->fecha_inicio;
        $fechaFin2 = $v->fecha_fin;
        $intervalo2 = new DateTime($fechaInicio2);
        $fechaFin2 = new DateTime($fechaFin2);

        // Encontrar las fechas de intersección
        $inicioInterseccion = max($intervalo1, $intervalo2);
        $finInterseccion = min($fechaFin1, $fechaFin2);

        // Verificar si hay intersección
        if ($inicioInterseccion <= $finInterseccion) {
            $coinciden = true;

            // Almacenar las fechas coincidentes
            $fechaActual = $inicioInterseccion;
            while ($fechaActual <= $finInterseccion) {
                $fechasCoincidentes[] = $fechaActual->format('Y-m-d');
                $fechaActual->modify('+1 day');
            }

            break; // Salir del bucle si se encuentra una coincidencia
        }
    }

    if ($coinciden) {
        return response()->json(['fechasCoincidentes' => $fechasCoincidentes], 200);
    } else {
        $resultado = $this->workers->setHolidays($request->input('inicio'), $request->input('fin'), $request->input('dni'));

        if ($resultado) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Registro insertado correctamente'], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Error al insertar el registro'], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces lo que hago es utilizar `max($intervalo1, $intervalo2)` para encontrar la fecha de inicio de la intersección y `min($fechaFin1, $fechaFin2)` para encontrar la fecha de fin de la intersección. Luego, se verifica si estas fechas se cruzan.

Si se encuentra una intersección, se almacenan las fechas coincidentes en el array `$fechasCoincidentes`. Finalmente, se devuelve este array como respuesta si hay coincidencias.

Documentacion relacionada:

[max()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php) y [min()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.min.php)